# I have duplicate contacts, Google Contacts not helping!

Tags: google-account, nexus-5

I have several contacts in my phone which are duplicates. For example I have one contact "John Smith" which contains my friend John Smith's phone number. Then I have another contact name JohnSmith87 which is my friend John Smith's email address. And then I have another contact called JohnSmithin which is my friend John Smith's skype account. I'd ideally like to merge all of these into one contact. I tried Google Contacts, but when I searched, only contacts with a phone number stored in them would show up. Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a quick step-by-step guide to help you "join" your contacts - in other words, take two separate contacts and make them one!

1. Open the People application.
2. Navigate to one of your duplicate contacts (any one will do) and tap it to open it up.
3. In the top-right corner, tap the 3 dots. This is the settings menu. Select "Edit".
4. Again, in the top-right corner, tap the 3 dots. Select "Join".
5. Android will now ask you to select which contact to join this contact with. Select one of the other duplicates of this contact and Android will join the contacts into one contact!

Rinse and repeat until all of the duplicate contacts have been "joined" into one single contact.

Comment: I don't think this applies to the [Google Contacts app for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.contacts).

Answer (score 0):

About [Google Contacts](https://www.google.com/contacts/), are you sure that JohnSmith87 (the contact with no phone number) is not in the **Other Contacts** section?

If that's the case, you can select the contact, click the "Add to my contacts" button and than go back to My Contacts section.

Now you have both contacts and you can select them and merge.

I find much more easy and quick to manage my contacts from the web than from my device.